# Validity of homework question?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Is the following homework problem posed correctly?**

If $S$ is a sphere and $F$ satisfies the hypotheses of Stokes' theorem, show that $$\iint_{S}F\cdot ds =0.$$

**My intuition tells me that the problem should read:**

If $S$ is a sphere and $F$ satisfies the hypotheses of Stokes' theorem, show that $$\iint_{S}\nabla\times F\cdot ds =0.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the problem is not posed correctly. As a counterexample, let $S$ be a sphere of radius $R>0$ centered at the origin, and let $\vec F(\vec r)=\frac13\vec r$. The vector field $\vec F$ is obviously smooth everywhere, including in particular the region of integration; hence, it satisfies the hypotheses of Stokes' Theorem. Then, since $\nabla\cdot F=1$, by the Divergence Theorem

$$\iint_S\vec F \cdot d \vec a=\iiint_V\nabla\cdot F\,dV=\iiint_VdV=\frac43\pi R^3\neq 0.$$

Thus, the identity your homework question is asking you to show is not true.

I agree with your intuition here that the intended identity that you are supposed to show is $\iint_{S}\nabla\times \vec F\cdot d\vec a =0$. For starters, at least this identity happens to be true, as can be easily shown by Stokes' Theorem or the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: Well, to apply the Divergence Theorem, one more derivative is needed. We're not quite sure what the hypotheses are here! :)